# pyrebase4 AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'sign_in_with_email_and_password'

Tags: python, firebase, kivy, kivymd, pyrebase

I couldn't make a login screen with pyrebase4. I'm getting this error:

> AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute
> 'sign_in_with_email_and_password'

Creating user is also not possible and it gives the error:

> AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute
> 'create_user_with_email_and_password'

I'm using pyrebase4 since I read that the original pyrebase was discontinued. I saw more than one video of people just writing the code exactly like I did and theirs seem to just work. I don't understand why mine doesn't.

- Python version: 3.10.4
- Kivy version: 2.1.0
- KivyMD version: 0.104.2
- Pyrebase4 version: 4.5.0

main.py

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
import pyrebase

class MainApp(MDApp):
    
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file('main.kv')
    
    firebaseConfig = {
        '''write your config here'''
    }
    firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(firebaseConfig)
    auth = firebase.auth
    
    def login(self):
        email = self.root.get_screen("test1win").ids.user_mail.text
        password = self.root.get_screen("test1win").ids.password.text
        
        login = self.auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password(email, password)
        self.root.current = "test2win"
        print("Login Success")

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class TestWindow1(Screen):
    pass

class TestWindow2(Screen):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

main.kv

```
#: include testwindow1.kv
#: include testwindow2.kv

WindowManager:
    TestWindow1:
    TestWindow2:
```

testwindow1.kv

```
<TestWindow1>:
    name: "test1win"
    Screen:
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            MDTextField:
                id: user_mail
                hint_text: "E-Mail"
                size_hint_x: 0.8
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
                font_size: 24
                mode: "rectangle"
            MDTextField:
                id: password
                hint_text: "Password"
                size_hint_x: 0.8
                font_size: 24
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
                mode: "rectangle"
            MDRaisedButton:
                text: "Login"
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
                on_release: app.login()
            Widget:
```

testwindow2.kv

```
<TestWindow2>:
    name: "test2win"
    Screen:
        MDLabel:
            text: "You're logged in"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your code:

```
auth = firebase.auth
```

should be:

```
auth = firebase.auth()
```

Note the parens.